# Consumindo dados de XML via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Estou precisando consumir os dados de um XML via AJAX mas o Firefox sempre retorna um erro de "formatação incorreta" e não imprime nada na tela.

O mesmo AJAX roda tranquilamente no Chrome, mas nos outros navegadores não carrega nada.

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.dino.com.br/v2/partners/mundo-do-marketing/news",
    dataType: "xml",    
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("NewsModel").each(function(){    
             //Título
             var titulo = $(this).find("Title").text();
             console.log(titulo);

             //Categoria
             var categoria = $(this).find("Categories");
             var tipo_categoria = categoria.find("NewsCategoryModel");
             var nome_categoria = tipo_categoria.first().find("Name").text();

             //Imagem
             var imagem = $(this).find("Image");
             var imagem_url = imagem.find("Url").text();

             //Data de Publicação
             var dataPublicacao = $(this).find("PublishedDate").text();

             var data = dataPublicacao;
             var data_brasil = data.substring(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/')

             //Link da api para cada conteúdo
             var id_conteudo = $(this).find("ReleaseId").text();

             var url_interna = 'https://www.mundodomarketing.com.br/dino/conteudo/' + id_conteudo + '/' + slug(titulo);

             //Monta a div que vai receber os textos e as imagens
             $('#dino').append('<div class="bloco-dino"><ul><li><a href="' + url_interna + '" title="' + titulo + '"><div class="item-dino"><div class="categoria-dino">' + nome_categoria + '</div><p class="titulo-dino">' + titulo + '</p><span class="data-dino">' + data_brasil + '</span></div></a></li></ul></div></br>');    
         });
    },    
 });
```

---

Isso é o que aparece no inspecionar.

[image: Esse é o erro que aparece]

Comment: Posta a mensagem de erro do Firefox.

Comment: Quando eu inspeciono elemento com o Firefox ele retorna "formatação incorreta" como (unknown)

Comment: Mas diz a linha ?

Comment: No lugar do número da linha ele exibe o unknown, é como se o Firefox simplesmente não visualiza-se os dados do XML. No Chrome ele roda de boa sem nenhuma mensagem no inspecionar.